# Application showing error Microsoft MsXml is not installed

Tags: xml-parsing, c++builder, c++builder-xe3

My application made using C++ builder XE3.
In my application i have done some xml parsing using XML.xmldoc.hpp

On XP machine when i run application it is showing me messagebox 
"Microsoft msxml is not installed".

Please can anyone help me??

Answer (score 4):

The error message is a little misleading.  It does not mean MSXML is not installed at all.  MSXML uses COM, and the error message actually means the MSXML COM object could not be instantiated via `CoCreateInstance()` (and the MSXML DOMVendor for `TXMLDocument` attempts to instantiate several different versions of MSXML before giving up). That is a subtle but important distinction to make.  For instance, if you are using the XMLDocument in a worker thread, you have to make sure you are calling `CoInitialize/Ex()` beforehand.  C++Builder does that for you in the main UI thread, but you have to do it manually in a worker thread.

Answer (score 0):

Problably you need to find the msxml6.dll installer ( standard with Windows 7)

XP worked with msxml4.0

[link download](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=3988)

Comment: i have another application which is working fine .. so first i thought i have to static link xmlrtl.bpi files of xe3 to the application. ..  i did it but then also it is not working . . my another application is not using msxml6.dll but still it is working fine.

Comment: Embarcadero's MSXML support is smart enough to start with v6 and load older versions as needed until either one succeeds or they all fail.

Comment: i got error at the statement . . _di_IXMLDocument pDoc = NewXMLDocument(L"1.0");

Comment: so i am not understanding why NewXMLDocument function call returns this message.

Comment: Which .bpi file i should include in package for the static linking

Comment: I fixed it . . in code CoInitializeEx was not called but CoUninitalize is called. . . i removed it and now it is working.